# Using string templates for making a quine in python?

Tags: python, stringtemplate, quine

I'm basically trying to make a quine in python and first tried with f-strings, but I quickly realized that I first have to define the variables I want to format inside the string. I then learned about string templates and figured that would be the way to go. I am however not that experienced with it and could need some help. Any suggestions?

Here's the actual code:

```
from string import Template
s="from string import Template\ns=$s\nt=Template($s).substitute(s=$s)\nprint($s)"
t=Template(s).substitute(s=s)
print(s)
```

It gives me somewhat of the right result. The only problem is that it's not replacing the `$s` with the actual string. I've might just have misunderstood the whole concept with quines and the method of doing them but I feel this should work.

Output:

```
from string import Template
s=$s
t=Template($s).substitute(s=$s)
print($s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken the advice from @Will Da Silva and included the `repr()` function in my method of doing it as seen below:

```
from string import Template
s='from string import Template\ns=$s\nt=Template(s)\nprint(t.substitute(s=repr(s)))'
t=Template(s)
print(t.substitute(s=repr(s)))
```

I think the problem was that it interpreted the string as code and in turn made a new line at every `\n`. But now when it keeps the quotation marks it just sees it as a string.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how this would be done using `string.Template`, but you could use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) as a straightforward replacement to f-strings that suits this task, as it allows you to delay the interpolation of the `s` variable:

```
s='s={0!r}\nprint(s.format(s))'
print(s.format(s))
```

Output:

```
s='s={0!r}\nprint(s.format(s))'
print(s.format(s))
```

The `!r` is used to get the `repr` of `s`, which wraps it in quotes, and escapes the newlines.

Comment: The key here is the `!r` modifier/directive, which uses `repr` instead of `str`. This is how you can recover the quotation marks, because th default `repr` implementation for strings is to return the string in quoted form, like what you would type in Python source code. I am not sure if there is a way to do this with `string.Template`.

Comment: What is the ```0``` for in ```{0!r}```?

Comment: The index of the element provided to `str.format`, i.e. the first element we passed into `str.format`, which is `s`.